# Importing ERC20 token on Ganache silently fails

Tags: erc-20, metamask, ganache

I have deployed an ERC20 contract on my local Ganache network, I am trying to add it to Metamask. It seems to find it, but then fails to display it in my token list after import:

First I add the token by it's contract address, it finds the symbol/decimals okay:

[image: First I add the token by it's contract address, it finds the symbol/decimals okay]

Then in seeing it found the correct token + amounts I click to import:

[image: Then in seeing it found the correct token + amounts I click to import]

but then after loading for a moment it is back to the token list without the new token:

[image: but then after loading for a moment it is back to the token list without the new token]

Comment: This is a bug on metamask right now